# Foreman does not start. HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.'

Tags: python, django, heroku, gunicorn, foreman

I am trying to deploy the project on Heroku.

This is the content of my Procfile and :

```
web: gunicorn --pythonpath meraki meraki.wsgi
```

and when I do `foreman start` I get this error:

```
10:37:44 web.1    | started with pid 10205
10:37:44 worker.1 | started with pid 10207
10:37:44 web.1    | [2015-05-25 10:37:44 +0000] [10205] [INFO]     Starting gunicorn 19.3.0
10:37:44 web.1    | [2015-05-25 10:37:44 +0000] [10205] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (10205)
10:37:44 web.1    | [2015-05-25 10:37:44 +0000] [10205] [INFO] Using worker: sync
10:37:44 web.1    | [2015-05-25 10:37:44 +0000] [10218] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10218
10:37:44 web.1    | [2015-05-25 10:37:44 +0000] [10218] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
10:37:44 web.1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
10:37:44 web.1    |   File "/home/maverick/.virtualenvs/meraki/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 507, in spawn_worker
10:37:44 web.1    |     worker.init_process()
10:37:44 web.1    |   File    "/home/maverick/.virtualenvs/meraki/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 118, in init_process
10:37:44 web.1    |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
10:37:44 web.1    |   File "/home/maverick/.virtualenvs/meraki/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
10:37:44 web.1    |     self.callable = self.load()
10:37:44 web.1    |   File "/home/maverick/.virtualenvs/meraki/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
10:37:44 web.1    |     return self.load_wsgiapp()
10:37:44 web.1    |   File "/home/maverick/.virtualenvs/meraki/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
10:37:44 web.1    |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
10:37:44 web.1    |   File "/home/maverick/.virtualenvs/meraki/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 355, in import_app
10:37:44 web.1    |     __import__(module)
10:37:44 web.1    | ImportError: No module named wsgi
10:37:44 web.1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
10:37:44 web.1    |   File "/home/maverick/.virtualenvs/meraki/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 507, in spawn_worker
10:37:44 web.1    |     worker.init_process()
10:37:44 web.1    |   File "/home/maverick/.virtualenvs/meraki/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 118, in init_process
10:37:44 web.1    |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
10:37:44 web.1    |   File "/home/maverick/.virtualenvs/meraki/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
10:37:44 web.1    |     self.callable = self.load()
10:37:44 web.1    |   File "/home/maverick/.virtualenvs/meraki/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
10:37:44 web.1    |     return self.load_wsgiapp()
10:37:44 web.1    |   File "/home/maverick/.virtualenvs/meraki/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
10:37:44 web.1    |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
10:37:44 web.1    |   File "/home/maverick/.virtualenvs/meraki/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 355, in import_app
10:37:44 web.1    |     __import__(module)
10:37:44 web.1    | ImportError: No module named wsgi
10:37:44 web.1    | [2015-05-25 10:37:44 +0000] [10218] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10218)
10:37:44 web.1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
10:37:44 web.1    |   File "/home/maverick/.virtualenvs/meraki/bin/gunicorn", line 11, in <module>
10:37:44 web.1    |     sys.exit(run())
10:37:44 web.1    |   File "/home/maverick/.virtualenvs/meraki/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 74, in run
10:37:44 web.1    |     WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
10:37:44 web.1    |   File "/home/maverick/.virtualenvs/meraki/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 189, in run
10:37:44 web.1    |     super(Application, self).run()
10:37:44 web.1    |   File "/home/maverick/.virtualenvs/meraki/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
10:37:44 web.1    |     Arbiter(self).run()
10:37:44 web.1    |   File "/home/maverick/.virtualenvs/meraki/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 174, in run
10:37:44 web.1    |     self.manage_workers()
10:37:44 web.1    |   File "/home/maverick/.virtualenvs/meraki/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 477, in manage_workers
10:37:44 web.1    |     self.spawn_workers()
10:37:44 web.1    |   File "/home/maverick/.virtualenvs/meraki/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 541, in spawn_workers
10:37:44 web.1    |     time.sleep(0.1 * random.random())
10:37:44 web.1    |   File "/home/maverick/.virtualenvs/meraki/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 214, in handle_chld
10:37:44 web.1    |     self.reap_workers()
10:37:44 web.1    |   File "/home/maverick/.virtualenvs/meraki/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 459, in reap_workers
10:37:44 web.1    |     raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
10:37:44 web.1    | gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
10:37:44 web.1    | exited with code 1
10:37:44 system   | sending SIGTERM to all processes
10:37:44 worker.1 | terminated by SIGTERM
```

the same thing was working yesterday ( I know this is classic :) )

How can I fix this?

Comment: `ImportError: No module named wsgi` Did you install wsgi with any specific virtualenv ?

Comment: @TheMonk yes and `wsgi.py` is in `meraki/meraki/wsgi.py` (meraki is the project name)

Comment: Could you launch python shell command on the virtualenv and verify the `import wsgi` command?

Comment: @TheMonk yes. no error when I do `import wsgi` in the shell. Maybe it is because my `Procfile` is outside the project root?

Comment: might as well, could try run the `Procfile` with the context of the specific virtualenv?

Comment: I am sorry but I don't quite get the question. run `Procfile`? virtualenv is activated and I am doing `foreman start` to run `Procfile`

Comment: Try use `--pythonpath meraki/meraki` i mean `path/to/project`

Comment: It wont work because you have to show the moduel name first @itzmeontv

Comment: can you just look into https://techtalkontv.wordpress.com/2015/05/16/deploy-django-app-in-heroku/